# Relationship Error When Foreign Key is Null in Laravel Vue.Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This my function newproject

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id' , 'user_id');
    }
```

This my function user

```
public function newproject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Newproject::class,'user_id','id');
    }
```

this my controller

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $newproject = Newproject::findOrFail($id);  
        $data=[
            Newproject::with('User')->find($id)
        ];
        return $data;
    }
```

my vue

```
    <tr v-for="show in detail" :key="show.id">

        <td>{{show.id}}</td>
        <td>{{show.user.name}}</td>
    </tr>
```

why when the foreign key is null it always getting error like this

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"

found in

---> <Projectwork> at resources/js/components/projectwork.vue
       <Root>
```

please help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put **unsigned ()**  in schema like this form

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and you can check the doc below for more information

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations